# is Excel function OR() incorrect?

Tags: excel

Is there any reason in an Excel spreadsheet the expression OR(TRUE,#N/A) returns #N/A ?
How can we make it work the way we learned at school ie. OR(TRUE, whatever) should equal TRUE ? 
so that we can evaluate a logical expression correctly even if not all parameters are known at the time of running, if those unknown are not really required.
Thank you

PS.

1. i use #N/A where the input is not known yet, it is not meant to be
   an    error. For instance
   "=OR(turnover>1000000,leadtime>90,AND(turnover>500000,leadtime>30),AND(turnover>200000,leadtime>60))"
   indicates an item needs special attention either because its
   turnover    is high or because its lead time is long but i don't
   always have    inputs for both. Sometimes one of two should suffice.
2. N/A is used when not known because i haven't found anything better than that. Tried "Unknown" string and AND(TRUE,"Unknown")
   returns TRUE, which is not what it should be
3. i have many expressions which are more complicated than just
   OR(x1,x2) so instead of trapping every parameter for error i have
   written an udf OOR where OOR(TRUE,whatever even if error) = TRUE.
   Just wondering if Microsoft has a   better approach i don't know

Comment: You cannot compare to an error without throwing an error. Use ISERROR on the cell.

Comment: Can add some example

Comment: fwiw, in your simplified example, it doesn't matter what *whatever* is as long as it is not an error since `OR(TRUE, <whatever>)` will always return true. A better example may be in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the logicals in an IFERROR that returns FALSE:

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(A1=1,FALSE),IFERROR(B1=1,FALSE)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare to an error without throwing an error. Use ISERROR or ISNA on the cell to see if it contains an error.

```
=IF(OR(A1=TRUE,ISERROR(A1)), <something if true>, <something if false>)
```

In the above, you don't need to say `A1 = TRUE`, simply `A1` will return true or false.